# Is it appropriate to create a stop watch web app based on firebase?

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, nosql

Is it appropriate to create a stop watch web app based on firebase?

Actually what I want to know is that :

whenever the stop watch's time change every second ,

is it appropriate to update the changed time into firebase DB every second?

Comment: What are your concerns?

Comment: Do you actually need to track every second between a start time and end time or is just the start time and end time sufficient? i.e. do you have an event that occurs every second between a start and end time?

Comment: I need to track every second

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I want to know whether it is a not bad idea concerning data efficiencity.

Comment: Keeping the current time (in a reasonable format) and updating it every second takes a trivial amount of storage. Setting it from one client/server and broadcasting it out to N connected clients also doesn't take a significant amount of bandwidth. But what is the goal here? Computers have pretty decent clocks. So if you just want the machines to show a reasonably accurate synchronized time, you could probably just set/synchronize a value periodically and then locally count the seconds.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen What I want to do is making a real time (group) stop watch app. In the app , there is a room for 4 users. Each user can see an each user's stop watch in real time.

Comment: OK. So it sounds like I gave you a recipe for that in my last comment: sync the start of each stopwatch via Firebase, then have every client count the seconds locally and periodically resync them to ensure they're all still on track. When you get stuck, post a question with the relevant code and we can help further.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I really appreciated that whenever I stuck about firebase, you always help! Thank you so much !!